# Calculating an identity for a mean

Tags: probability, means

We are given a Random variable X~$B(n,1/4)$.

Another RV is defined as $T=4^x$.
How can I calcualte $E(T)$ (the mean for T)?

I've tried working with various identities for the mean or using the density function of the Binom but I'm affraid I'm completly stuck on this one, help would be much apprecieted.

Comment: $T$ takes values $4^1, \cdots, 4^n$. $P(T = 4^k) = P(X = k)$, if $c \neq 4^k$ for some k, then $P(X = c) = 0$. Then use the formula, $E(T) = \sum_{k} k\cdot P(T = k)$, since you will be summing over finitely many values of k

Comment: If $n = 10,$ then the computational solution in R statistical software (where `dbinom` denotes PDF) is `x=0:10; sum(x^4*dbinom(x,10,1/4))`, which gives
$129.0625.$ // For an algebraic solution maybe see how $E(X)=np$ is derived from the PDF formula and modify as needed. // If you know about MGF's maybe that's easier.